# How to modify jetty-home-11.0.6\etc\*.xml files

Tags: eclipse, webserver, jetty, application-server, jetty-10

I am updating Jetty9 to Jetty11 and Understood the concept of Jetty-Home and Jetty-Base directory. and my question is how to modify the below files as Jeety-Home is the read-only directory and should not update in the Jetty-Home directory.

1. etc\jetty.XML
2. etc\webdefault.XML
3. etc\jetty-requestlog.xml
4. lib\jetty-http-11.0.6.jar\org\eclipse\jetty\http (To add MimeTypes)

I was reading about the custom Jetty module concept but couldn't get much information. Is this the way to do it ?
Please share reference docs if any

I used to modify the above-mentioned files directly in jetty-distribution-9.4.43.v20210629.

Exa :- I have to modify the below attributes like

```
1. jetty.httpConfig.sendServerVersion to false in etc\jetty.xml
2. Increased the query params to 10000 in etc\jetty.xml.
        <Call name="setAttribute">
            <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormKeys</Arg>
            <Arg>10000</Arg>
        </Call>
3. set development mode to false in etc\webdefault.xml  
<init-param>
 <param-name>development</param-name>
 <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
4. add below MIME Types in mime.properties file under lib\jetty-http-11.0.6.jar\org\eclipse\jetty\http folder
     appcache=text/cache-manifest
     ttf=application/font-sfnt
```

Comment: What are you wanting to change specifically in each file? (give an example).   As there's often a solution that doesn't require changing the XML.

Comment: I have updated question with examples.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt can we use <context-param>to set org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormKeys as suggested by this link - https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2325

Comment: That's an old rejected issue, use the XML deployable outlined in the answer below instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you will see, you have changed nothing in your `${jetty.home}` directory in order to accomplish your end goals.

> 1. `jetty.httpConfig.sendServerVersion` to false in `etc\jetty.xml`

That's a property, just define the value you want in your appropriate `${jetty.base}/start.d/*.ini` file.

> 2. Increased the query params to `10000` in `etc\jetty.xml`.
>
> ```
>        <Call name="setAttribute">
>            <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormKeys</Arg>
>            <Arg>10000</Arg>
>        </Call>
> ```

That won't work as a Server property or attribute.

If you want to configure maxFormKeys, you do that for the specific webapp and/or context.

Use the documented XML deployable for your webapp and set the `maxFormKeys`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_10_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  ... other configuration for your webapp ...
  <Set name="maxFormContentSize">400000</Set>
  <Set name="maxFormKeys">400</Set>
</Configure>
```

> 3. set development mode to false in `etc\webdefault.xml`
>
> ```
> <init-param>
>   <param-name>development</param-name>
>   <param-value>false</param-value>
> </init-param>
> ```
>
> 4. add below MIME Types in mime.properties file under lib\jetty-http-11.0.6.jar\org\eclipse\jetty\http folder
>
> ```
>     appcache=text/cache-manifest
>     ttf=application/font-sfnt
> ```

For both of these, the correct place to configure them is your webapp specific descriptor.

Note: that the `mime.properties` defines the `MimeTypes` defaults, and the values in `MimeTypes` are only used for serving static content from the `DefaultServlet`.

For custom descriptor behavior, you configure that in your specific webapp and/or context.

You can:

1. declare the entire new default descriptor with `<Set name="defaultsDescriptor">...location...</Set>`
2. or provide a replacement descriptor to apply after the default descriptor, which is just a diff of changes from the default descriptor. `<Set name="overrideDescriptor">...location...</Set>`
3. or provide that entries you want in your `WEB-INF/web.xml` descriptor.

For option 1 (*this approach is not recommended, as you are stomping on the version in jetty itself, and wont get fixes/updates/improvements that come with newer versions of Jetty*), copy the entire contents of `webdefault.xml` into a new file in your `${jetty.base}/etc/`,
and reference it in your XML deployable `${jetty.base}/webapps/<name>.xml` like this ...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_10_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  ... other configuration for your webapp ...  
  <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.base" default="."/>/etc/custom-default-descriptor.xml</Set>
</Configure>
```

For option 2 (*best server level option*) `${jetty.base}/etc/override-web.xml`
and option 3 (*most correct use of servlet spec*) `WEB-INF/web.xml` the descriptor is only the differences from default, and would looks like this...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
   metadata-complete="false"
   version="3.1" >

  <servlet id="jsp">
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>development</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>appcache</extension>
    <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>ttf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/font-sfnt</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

For option 2, you reference it in your `${jetty.base}/webapps/<name>.xml` like this ...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_10_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  ... other configuration for your webapp ...  
  <Set name="overrideDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.base" default="."/>/etc/override-web.xml</Set>
</Configure>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate all your help

Comment: can we use <context-param>to set org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormKeys as suggested by this link - https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2325